# FTP in perl error?

Tags: perl

Is there anything wrong the script bewlow, because I just can't login.....
And I'm sure I'm using the right username and password.
(Cannot login Login incorrect.)

```
sub UploadToFTPServer()
{
my $filename = shift;


$ftp = Net::FTP->new($FTPSERVER, Debug => 0) ;
if ($ftp) {     
    eval {
        $ftp->login($USERNAME,$PASSWORD)   or warn "Cannot login ", $ftp->message;
        $ftp->binary();

        $ftp->putfile($filename) or warn "Cannot upload ($filename)", $ftp->message;
        $ftp->quit();
    };
}
else {
    warn "Cannot connect to $FTPSERVER: $@";
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it's a bug with your script and not your credentials? Did you verify those?

Comment: Your not authenticating properly. Check your username and password and try to FTP with a different client and see if they work.

Comment: That's the point, the credentials do work with FireFTP.

Comment: Is it possible that you have a copy/paste error with the credentials? Can you add `warn qq{UN: '$USERNAME' PW: '$PASSWORD'};` to the script and make sure that they are correct when they are sent?

Comment: Ah, I see, it turns out when my username is something like "myname@gmail.com" it will turn it into "myname.com", that's really strange...

Comment: Either use single quotes or delimit the "@" like `myname\@gmail.com`. `use strict;` and `use warnings;` would have complained and caught this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start your script off with this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Then make sure that perl doesn't try to [interpolate](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) anything in your un/pw.

```
my $USERNAME = 'myname@gmail.com'; ## notice the single quotes
my $PASSWORD = 'mypass';
```

Given your error, it should work with those changes. It would have been easier to catch if the [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) pragmas were used from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Use the module "[Net::FTP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~wilco/Net-FTP-Simple-0.0007/lib/Net/FTP/Simple.pm)"

```
@send = Net::FTP::Simple->send_files({
    username        => $user,
    password        => $pass,
    server          => $host,
    remote_dir      => $path,
    debug_ftp       => 0,
    files           => [
        $file,
    ],
});

print "The following files were retrieved successfully:\n\t",
    join("\n\t", @send), "\n"
        if @send;
```

Comment: "PerlApp is not able to locate net\FTP\Simple.pm"

Comment: It looks like you have net::FTP::Simple, not Net::FTP::Simple. I'd expect that you have to install that from cpan. Either way, it wouldn't have fixed your authentication issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your testing from the same IP?

Also, try printing the username & password with quotes around them, as gpojd suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try $ftp->put instead of $ftp->putfile.  I don't see putfile in the documentation.